# Genymotion не запускает проект

Tags: java, android, genymotion

Установил Genymotion, но при запуске просто эмитируется телефон, а моего проекта нету. Как запустить приложение?

Установил плагин для Android Studio. Запускаю с его помощью, предлагают выбрать устройство, выбираю, потом просто экран телефона и стандартные приложения.

**Обновление**

С этим разобрался. Я запускал только эмулятор через плагин и думал, что этого достаточно для запуска проекта. Нужно еще было запустить проект. Теперь когда запускаю проект высвечивает вот это

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

Подскажите, будьте добры, что делать?

Comment: Что студия пишет?

Comment: Удалите приложение с эмулятора, если оно там есть. А если нет, то проверте версию системы на эмуляторе и ту, которую вы указали минимальной для проекта.

Comment: min sdk version и target sdk какие стоят в проекте? и какой Android на эмуляторе? дело в этом